# CKEditor text value is lost on post in BLAZOR

Tags: ckeditor, blazor

I have a Textarea control in a Blazor applicaiton that is a CKEditor 5 WYSIWYG editor.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">Content</label>
    <textarea id="editor" class="form-control" @bind="@PostObject.Content" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => PostObject.Content)" />
</div>
```

When the form gets submitted the value of PostObject.Content is always null. If I remove the CKEditor element the posted value is correct.

The CKEditor is initialised by calling a Javascript function called RTF on a button click (launches the form in a modal popup) -

```
await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("RTF", "editor");
```

The function is located in index.html

```
function RTF(editorId) {
    ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#' + editorId));
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this article to see how to properly integrate http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4364/Creating-A-Rich-Text-Editor-In-Blazor-Using-Quill.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For me works with the function CKEDITOR.editor.getData.
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_savedata.html

Your code can be changed to below

```
<EditForm Model="@postObject" OnValidSubmit="SaveObject">
    <div class="form-group">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <InputTextArea id="editor" @bind-Value="@PostObject.Content" Class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</EditForm>

@code {

    PostObject postObject= new PostObject();
   string contentFromEditor = string.Empty;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
          await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("RTF", "editor");
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    private async Task SaveObject()
    {
        contentFromEditor = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData");
    }

}
```